# Set voice message when phone is unreachable using android app

Tags: android, android-activity, listener

I am creating an android app in that

**Problem 1:-**
user can set message depends on events like "**Phone unreachable**", "**Caller tune**", "**I am busy call me later**" and caller could listen that.

Problem 2:-
If user is unreachable, that how i can start activity to play sound and send it to my listener.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not possible .. Restriction from the OS

Comment: @Nomi Can i set or play default audio before even call start ?

Comment: No bro.. actually android does not allow to play with call stuff.. :)
You can search and verify my statement.

Comment: @Nami "why such an app or even a basic feature is not there / possible". I never pick up calls while driving. So, I would like to leave a message "Am driving. Will call back later. Thanks"
below are discussion on same topic https://www.facebook.com/groups/blrstartups/permalink/735539486468192/?stream_ref=3

Comment: I dont know buddy but i have also tried that thing and did R&D about it... but its not yet possible in Android... if you get anything running then share with all devs here... You can answer your own question...it will help :)